# You got your double-encoded space in my tooltip

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, shop, encoding

It seems that the process used to generate the title attributes for the image links on the Stack Exchange store encodes an already-encoded string, leading to situations like this:

[image: Double-encoded title of the pen item image]

where the title attribute looks like the following:

```
title="Stack Exchange Pens — &amp;nbsp;Got some serious writing to do?&amp;nbsp; Get..."
```

We all know that Serious Writing™ necessitates spaces that don't break under pressure, but it'd be nice if they were a bit less intrusive. In this particular situation just removing the extra spaces it's trying to preserve from the [main product description](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-pens) would work, but I imagine it might be a more general issue.

Comment: I am now concerned about the quality of Stack Exchange writing implements. Were the tooltips written with either the Official SE Pen or the Official SE Sharpie? If not, why aren't you dogfooding? If so, will I experience similar issues with my writing when using your products?

Comment: `&nbsp;` are *extra strong* spaces. They can withstand pressure that a mere ` ` would crumble under. In the industry, we call them "load bearing spaces".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is now fixed.

Note to self: since this was [about the sixth highest rated bug on the bugs tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/?tab=bugs), I guess this means either a) we write *awesome* software that has almost *no* important bugs or b) our users have far too much time on their hands...

:)

Comment: Probably a bit of both, though I imagine the most important part of it all is that it didn't stop me from [buying one of those pens](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mm8sd.png) anyway. ;)