# Broken ampersand symbol

Tags: bug, status-completed, special-characters

It appears in the hint on flair tab in the profile page. Because of the «quality standards» i need to add some <s>dummy text</s> steps to reproduce this bug:

1. Open your profile
2. Select the flair tab
3. Move your mouse pointer to the last flair which represent your combined profiles

[image]

Comment: I see this as well. [Perhaps related to this report from the store](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94051/you-got-your-double-encoded-space-in-my-tooltip)? Something perhaps changed in the tool tip logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an encoding issue, it'll be fixed in the next build.