# Missing escape of ampersand in flair copy/paste code

Tags: bug, status-completed, flair

I'm working to comply with my required 37 pieces of flair, but notice there have been some previous questions about escaping:

- [Needless escape of ampersand in SO flair](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145531/needless-escape-of-ampersand-in-so-flair)
- [Broken ampersand symbol](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94142/broken-ampersand-symbol)
- [combined flair tooltip looks broken because img title uses `&amp;` instead of ampersand](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160288/combined-flair-tooltip-looks-broken-because-img-title-uses-amp-instead-of-am)

Seems if it isn't too much, it's too little...there's no escaping on the ampersand right now:

[image: no escaping of ampersand in flair]

If you feed the following HTML into the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) (bracketed for HTML5):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head><title>Nothing</title></head>
<body>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/211160/hostilefork">
<img src="http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/211160.png" width="208" height="58" alt="profile for HostileFork at Stack Overflow, Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers" title="profile for HostileFork at Stack Overflow, Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers">
</a>
</body>
```

You get the error:

> & did not start a character reference. (& probably should have been escaped as `&amp;`.)

Comment: You posted wrong screenshot. There's nothing wrong in it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Copying and pasting `Q&A` into a page directly makes the W3C validator unhappy.  The previous complaints were about `Q&amp;ampA`.  I'm assuming the correct answer is supposed to be `Q&amp;A`.

Comment: OK, it's not clear from your question at all. Better link to http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/syntax.html#attributes-0 and quoute relevant part, about [ambiguous ampersand](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/syntax.html#syntax-ambiguous-ampersand).

Comment: @ShadowWizard Well, I just sort of operate on the "ampersands always escaped" assumption in raw HTML.  But I added a sample that the W3C validator chokes on.  I'm not sure it would fit the definition of an ambiguous ampersand, as that suggests it's for when an entity ends with a semicolon but can't be identified as [one of these](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/named-character-references.html#named-character-references)... so for instance `&asdfieryasdf;`.

Comment: Good edit, cheers! I believe space also ends an entity so it's looking for `&A` which is not valid. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed in next build (`2013.2.3.1914` meta, `2013.2.3.1344` sites)