# Zero new answer notification

Tags: bug, notifications, notification-bar

I got this notification twice today:

[image]

I've already read this previous meta question: [0 new answer to this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143798/0-new-answer-to-this-question), but [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145918/160657) makes it sound like this issue was already resolved. Well, apparently this is still happening, and it's strange that I got this notification twice today and never before, so maybe a recent change made it resurface?.

Comment: *Stands up* I too have this problem.

Comment: It just wanted to let you know there haven't been any new answers yet.

Comment: Pluralization bug!

Comment: @BenBrocka Oh, you are right, how helpful of him :-)

Comment: Could it be due to someone posting an answer and then deleting it shortly there afterwards?

Comment: @alexy13 probably, since the question does have a deleted answer. But still, the answer to the previous meta question about this says that this is no longer an issue